# Wait for a component trigger on a message that's not an answer

Tags: javascript, button, discord, discord.js

I'm creating a game interaction command that allows player to play a 1vs1 game. I've done a system so that the bot answers to the command by asking the player who's defied to accept or not the game. After that, if he accepts it, a new channel is created and I'm sending in this channel a message with a button that has to be pressed to place some troops. The problem is, I can't seem to find a method to wait for the button interaction that works on a message that is not a direct reply to the interaction.

That is the code I use to send a message to the new channel :

```
const placingMessage = battleChan.send({
  content:`text`, components:[placingRow]
})
```

Then I want to fetch any button click like this:

```js
const placingButton = await placingMessage.awaitMessageComponent({ 
  filter: (user) => user.user.id === opponentId || sender.id,
  time: 30000,
}).catch( // some code )

The problem is, when I do this, it doesn't work (the error is : " placingMessage.awaitMessageComponent is not a function ") And I know this is because placingMessage is not an answer. 

Is there any way I could listen to the button presses without using a direct answer ? Because I don't know how I could change the channel in which I'm answering and I would actually like to use this method of waiting for some button or context menu press a lot of times in this new channel in order for the game to work. 

Thanks by advance.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because `placingMessage` is a promise and when you try to use `await placingMessage.awaitMessageComponent` you don't actually resolve this. You'll need to use `await` in front of `battleChan.send` too:

```js
const placingMessage = await battleChan.send({
  content: `text`,
  components: [placingRow],
}).catch(/* handle error */);

const placingButton = await placingMessage
  .awaitMessageComponent({
    filter: (user) => user.user.id === opponentId || sender.id,
    time: 30000,
  })
  .catch(/* handl error */);
```